# Meu componente dentro do meu modal está renderizando duas vezes

Tags: react

Possuo um componente pai que abre um modal baseado no valor desta variável:

```
const [openFullScreenModal, setOpenFullScreenModal] = useState(false)
```

Possuo um botão neste componente que seta o vaor desta variável para `true`:

```
setOpenFullScreenModal(true)
```

No meu template, eu possuo um modal que abre quando o valor dessa variável é true:

```
{ openFullScreenModal === true ? 
    <ModalFullScreen
        FormComponent={UsersFormPermissionsGroupPermissions}
        title="Permissões do grupo"
        onCloseModal={setOpenFullScreenModal}
        open={openFullScreenModal}
    />
    :
    <> </>
}
```

Este é meu **ModalFullScreen** component:

```
const ModalFullScreen = (props) => {

    const { title, FormComponent, open, onCloseModal } = props
    const classes = modalFullScreenStyles()

    const handleClose = () => {
        onCloseModal(false)
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Dialog fullScreen open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
                <AppBar className={classes.appBar}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                            {title}
                        </Typography>
                        <IconButton edge="start" color="inherit" onClick={handleClose} aria-label="fechar">
                            <Typography variant="h6" className={classes.title}>
                                Cancelar
                            </Typography>
                        </IconButton>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>

                <FormComponent></FormComponent>

            </Dialog>
        </div>
    )
```

No meu **UsersFormPermissionsGroupPermissions** componente eu uso um `useEffect()` para buscar dados de uma api:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('mounted again')
    dispatch(groupPermissionsActions.getPermissionsGroupById(idGroupCompany))
})
```

Eu percebi que minha api estava sendo chamada duas vezes, então coloquei esse `console.log()` e confirmei que meu componente está sendo re-renderizado duas vezes quando eu clico no botão do meu componente pai para abrir esse modal, meu modal abre e o componente que eu estou passando para o modal é renderizado duas vezes.

Porque isso está acontecendo?

Comment: Quando esse `UsersFormPermissionsGroupPermissions` é criado e depois ele atualiza, automáticamente o componente relacionado também atualiza, Talvez seja isso e sua observação de renderização é muito pertinente, como não temos o código total fica complicado dizer mas, de cara eu faria assim, no componente Pai dos dois componentes eu resgatava as informações e por `props`passava para esse outro componente assim o Pai fica responsável em enviar somente informações para os filhos.

Comment: Não é que ele está renderizando duas deves, ele cria o componente e depois atualiza o componente com o processo assíncrono se já poderia enviar a informação para ele antes de abrir

Comment: @VirgilioNovic realmente, depois que faço o dispatch ele renderiza o componente de novo. Você pode prover um exemplo de como posso passar uma propriedade para o componente que meu modal vai renderizar? Eu tentei algo como: <ModalFullScreen
                    FormComponent={UsersFormPermissionsGroupPermissions propriedadePassar="teste"} porém recebo "}" expected

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu acidentalmente esqueci de colocar o [] após o useEffect, então após qualquer ação ele estava renderizando meu componente de novo. Eu consegui corrigir facilmente com:     useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(groupPermissionsActions.getPermissionsGroupById(idGroupCompany))
    }, [])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou deixar um exemplo mesmo assim, com o `useEffect` para renderizar o componente e após isso atualizar uma variável local de estado para carregar as informações não gerando assim renderização desnecessárias, exemplo:

```js
function Modal({onClose}) {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState({});
  const loadData = () => {
    fetch('https://viacep.com.br/ws/01001000/json/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => setData(response));
  }  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    loadData();
  }, []);    
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Modal</h1>
      <button onClick={onClose}>Close</button>
      <h3>Data</h3>
      <ul>
        { data && (<li>{data.cep}</li>) }
        { data && (<li>{data.localidade}</li>) }
        { data && (<li>{data.logradouro}</li>) }
      </ul>
    </div>
  )  
}

function Pai() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);  
  const onClose = () => { 
    setOpen(false);
  }
  const onOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      {open && <Modal onClose={onClose}/>}
      {!open && (<button onClick={onOpen}>Open</button>)}
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( <Pai/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Obrigado pela disposição, no meu caso, a chamada para a api deve ser feita através do componente pai e passar para o filho por props ou; ser feita no componente filho do modal pois o modal neste projeto é apenas uma "casca" e não deve guardar estados exclusivos de algum componente

Comment: No que eu percebi agora pode ser feito no filho igual no meu exemplo, o efeito foi o que você esperava tendo na criação uma única renderização do componente ... @veroneseComS , apesar do meu comentário foi feito em cima de não ver o que você tinha feito no componente, é sempre bom colocar todos os componentes a próxima vez ... faltava mesmo o `[]` no useEffect que significa após criação execute essa função uma unica vez ...

Comment: Sim, meu problema aconteceu porque eu esqueci de colocar o [] após o useEffect, ao colocar, renderizou apenas uma vez, mesmo estando a chamada da api no filho.